# Interesting examples of minimal action on torus

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, finite-groups

Edit 1:This is a cross post on MSE. See [math.stackexchange.com/q/289595/12952](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289595/12952)

Edit 2:I originally asked for finite group actions as I thought that will be easier. But as pointed out by Victor minimal action does not exist for finite groups. So I am asking for general discrete group actions. What I really want to know is some interesting examples of minimal actions (not just a single homeomorphism) on suitable nice topological space. I just read an article on Furstenburg transformation am I was guessing the construction could be generalized to give minimal actions.

For a n-torus $\mathbb{T}^n$, A Furstenburg transformation $\phi$ is defined by:
$$
\phi(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots,\xi_n)=(e^{2\pi i\theta}\xi_1, f_1(\xi_1)\xi_2,\dots,f_{n-1}(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_{n-1})\xi_n)
$$
Where $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ and for each $i$, $f_i$ is a real continuous function on $\mathbb{T}^i$.

It is known that when $\theta$ is irrational, (Edit3: and all functions $f_i$ are in suitable homotopy classes not containing the constant functions) Furstenburg transformation defines a minimal dynamic system.

My question is, are there any interesting examples of minimal actions of other discrete groups on n-torus? I am thinking something similar to Furstenburg transformation, but any other examples are welcome too.

Comment: No: finite groups have finite (and hence closed) orbits. 

Comment: You should mention when you crosspost a question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/289595/12952) to MSE so that when it is answered on one site, people on the other site will know about it.

Comment: If the functions $f_1,\ldots,f_{n-1}$ are all constant and equal to the identity then $\phi$ is not minimal.

Comment: Take a minimal foliation of the torus given by some action of a connected Lie group $G$ (e.g. the Kronecker foliation). Take $\Gamma$ any dense subgroup in $G$. Restrict the action from $G$ to $\Gamma$, and get a minimal action of $\Gamma$. 

Comment: When considering the one-dimensional torus, you have lots of interesting examples. The firsts coming to my mind are Fuchsian groups (of first kind) or the action of Thompson's group $G$.

In the differentiable world there are many beautiful results and conjectures, as you can read in a paper by Deroin, Klepstyn and Navas (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1974.pdf)

Comment: @Lee Mosher Yes you are right, thanks for pointing this out. The correct statement should be that the functions $f_i$ are in suitable homotopy classes other than the one containing constant functions. The details are in Theorem 2.1 of Furstenberg's paper STRICT ERGODICTICY AND TRANSFORMATION OF THE TORUS and the remark after it.

Comment: @ Alain Valette @ Michele Triestino Thanks! 